# Flutter DropdownButton get value from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter

So I making an app in which I have `DropdownButton`. I want to get the value parameter from SharedPreferences. But `SharedPreferences.getInstance` returns `Future`, not `String`. How could I return a `String` instead of `Future`?

This is a function for reading from `SharedPreferences`

```
_read() async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final key = 'cur_r';
      final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? "";
      print('read: $value');
      return value;
    }
```

Here is the dropdown Button code:

```
 body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: __read(),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue;
              _save(newValue);
              _read();
            });
          },
          items: ['one', 'two', 'three']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),

      ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a better approach of doing it.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // make all of them instance variable
  String dropdownValue;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  final _key = 'cur_r';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _read(); // read in initState 
  }

  _read() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = prefs.getString(_key) ?? "one"; // get the value
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("")),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue;
            });
            prefs.setString(_key, dropdownValue); // save value to SharedPreference
          },
          items: ['one', 'two', 'three'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```